# Android studio 2.0 - Error while Launching activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to run my app this i get the following error:

```
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.amran.myapplication/com.example.amran.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

This is the code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And this is the Logcat output:

```
04-14 14:55:28.507 2521-2528/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-14 14:55:43.777 2549-2549/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
04-14 14:55:43.839 2549-2549/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
04-14 14:55:44.438 2549-2549/? I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
04-14 14:55:44.508 2549-2549/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
04-14 14:55:44.908 2549-2549/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
04-14 14:55:44.908 2549-2549/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
04-14 14:55:44.948 2549-2549/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
04-14 14:55:45.285 2549-2549/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
04-14 14:55:45.344 2549-2549/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-14 14:55:45.455 2549-2556/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

Comment: Post your complete logcat and MainActivity code.

Comment: how do i get the logcat?

Comment: From same place where you are getting the above error.

Comment: `Android Monitor` tab will have your debug/error messages.

Comment: looking into that now , thanks